# Prove $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ is in $L^p(R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f \notin S(R^n)$ because $f$ is not differentiable at the origin. But the function can be in $L^p(R^n)$?

Comment: Compare $e^{-p|x|}$ to something known to be integrable.

Comment: $e^{-p|x|}<e^{-p|x_1|}$

Comment: But $e^{-p|x_1|}$ is not integrable on $\mathbb R^n$ when $n \ge 2$..

Comment: Why is not integrable?

Comment: Because $e^{-p|x_1|}$ is constant with respect to any other coordinate. What's the integral of a constant from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$ is convex. Hence, for any $n$ points $x_1^2,...,x_n^2$, we can say
\begin{align}
-|x|&=-\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2} \\
&=f(\frac{n}{n}(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)) \\
&=\sqrt{n}f(\frac{1}{n}(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)) \\
&\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\left(f(x_1^2)+...+f(x_n^2)\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(|x_1|+...+|x_n|).
\end{align}
In conclusion, $e^{-|x|}\leq e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(|x_1|+...+|x_n|)}=\prod_{j=1}^n e^{-\frac{|x_j|}{\sqrt{n}}}$. There should be no challenges performing the iterated integral.

Comment: This is true also for $e^{-p|x|}$?

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{R^n} (e^{-|x|})^p dx \le\int_{R^n} \prod_{j=1}^{n} e^\frac{-p|x_j|}{\sqrt n} dx=\prod_{j=1}^{n}\int_{R}e^\frac{-p|x_j|}{\sqrt n}dx_j=\frac{2n\sqrt n}{p}$.
So $f \in L^p, \forall p\ge1$?

Comment: You missed the inequality at the first st ep. Also, please don't write $|e^{-|x|}|$. Instead, write $e^{-|x|}$. Since $e$ to anything is positive, the extra absolute value is unnecessary and annoying.

Comment: I've correct my error